# How can I set multiple menus to the left in winforms devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

[image]

Currently, this is going to be done, but I want to automatically adjust or size the menus to fit the size of the panel. It is now leaning to the left. I must use devexpress.
Other than that, it just needs to look like the image.The page on the right will be changed through the menu button.

I used barmanager and bar.
the setting is

```
MenuManager (barmanager)

this.MenuManager.AllowQuickCustomization = false;
this.MenuManager.Bars.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.Bar[] {
this.MainMeun_bar});
this.MenuManager.DockControls.Add(this.barDockControlTop);
this.MenuManager.DockControls.Add(this.barDockControlBottom);
this.MenuManager.DockControls.Add(this.barDockControlLeft);
this.MenuManager.DockControls.Add(this.barDockControlRight);
this.MenuManager.Form = this.menupanel;
this.MenuManager.MainMenu = this.MainMeun_bar;

MainMeun_bar (bar)

this.MainMeun_bar.BarName = "MainMeun_bar";
this.MainMeun_bar.DockCol = 0;
this.MainMeun_bar.DockRow = 0;
this.MainMeun_bar.DockStyle = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarDockStyle.Left;
this.MainMeun_bar.OptionsBar.DrawBorder = false;
this.MainMeun_bar.OptionsBar.DrawDragBorder = false;
this.MainMeun_bar.OptionsBar.MultiLine = true;
this.MainMeun_bar.OptionsBar.RotateWhenVertical = false;
this.MainMeun_bar.OptionsBar.UseWholeRow = true;
this.MainMeun_bar.Text = "Main menu";           

mainMenuItem.OptionsMultiColumn.ImageVerticalAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.ItemVerticalAlignment.Center;
mainMenuItem.ContentHorizontalAlignment = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemContentAlignment.Center;
```